# converting a Pandas series into a table

Tags: python-3.x

I want to convert the series output into a table, how do I do that?

```
inventory = bpd.read_csv('inventory.csv')
inventory = inventory.groupby('fruit name').sum()
inventory = inventory.get('sold count')
inventory


fruit name
apple         19
grape         17
kiwi          30
orange        30
peach         20
strawberry    37
Name: sold count, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to turn the output of the `groupby` you are applying (which returns a Series for this case) into a dataframe, you can simply use `to_frame()` or an optional method would be `reset_index()` on the returning object and that will make it a dataframe.

For the first case you only need:

```
df_inventory = inventory.to_frame()
```

For the second example:

```
df_inventory = inventory.reset_index()
```

Furthermore you might have to rename the column in case the name doesn't match what you expect. You can do it with:

```
df_inventory = inventory.reset_index().rename(columns={'col_name':'desired_name'})
```